# mgt-person in Angular - the parameter "user-id" not working with variables

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-toolkit

Using the mgt-person component in Angular with the parameter "user-id" not working with variables.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
  <mgt-person user-id="[[user]]" view="threeLines">
  </mgt-person>
</ng-container>
```

```
TemplateHelper.setBindingSyntax('[[', ']]');
```

have you any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting [custom binding syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/use-toolkit-with-angular#customizing-components-with-angular) works only inside `<template>` elements.

Here you're outside `<template>` so you have to use angular binding.

```html
<mgt-person [user-id]="user" view="threeLines"></mgt-person>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Kamil but with property name (and not attribute name)

```
<mgt-person [userId]="user" view="threeLines"></mgt-person>
```